# Overriding/blocking __set__ on db.Property to enforce an alternate set method/process

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to sub-class `db.Property` and override the **set** method to implement stuff like pre and post set logic.

The problem is that `__set__` is being called directly on the property by `db.Model.__init__()` during the `from_entity` conversion of entity to instance (after it comes out of the datastore), so obviously pre and post set logic should not be called.

```
class MyProperty(db.StringProperty):
    def __set__(model_instance, value):
        self.pre_set(value)
        super(MyProperty.__set__(model_instance, value)
        self.post_set(value)


class MyModel(db.Model):
    foo = MyProperty()

my_model = MyModel()
my_model.put()
my_model.foo = u'A new string.' """pre/post set logic runs."""

#onload the __set__ method will be called again
loaded_model = db.get(my_model.key())

# In db.Model.__init__()
for prop in self.properties().values():
    value = kwargs.get(prop.name, None) or prop.default() #or something like that
    prop.__set__(self, value) """pre/post set logic also runs :("""
```

How can I differentiate between these two occurrences without having to override `db.Model.__init__()`? or should I just do that? Am I not supposed to be doing this with `prop.__set__()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to distinguish the two situations. You could examine the stack, but that's an extremely kludgy approach. You could override `Model.__init__` - either by monkeypatching it or by requiring users of your property extend your custom model subclass - but I'm not sure how you'd modify it in a way that would help yet remain backwards compatible with existing property classes.

You might want to check out [Guido's NDB project](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) - it may be more flexible in this respect, and is still under active development.

Comment: The path of least resistance as I see it is overriding `db.Model.__init__()` to pass the `_from_entity` argument onto the `__set__` (line 910) if the property is an instance of my subclassed `BaseProperty`. Then the property can make it's own decisions again about whether or not to run pre/post set logic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to ndb also. I previously thought the project was only related to asynchronous querying, but now I see it changes everything. I'm a big fan of the `ListProperty` implementation (`StringProperty(repeated=True,...)`). That's going to be very nice.